# Xcode 4.2 is very slow to save a file / frequently beach-balls

Tags: xcode4.2

I am using Xcode 4.2 for Lion / production version.  the previous version of Xcode 4 performed just fine.

every time i save a file and sometimes randomly, the beach-ball shows for 5-10 seconds for no apparent reason.

i am using subversion for what its worth.

i captured a sample and it seems to be somewhere in here:

```
1775 Thread_791676   DispatchQueue_1: com.apple.main-thread  (serial)
+ 1775 ???  (in Xcode)  load address 0x103392000 + 0xeec  [0x103392eec]
+   1775 NSApplicationMain  (in AppKit) + 867  [0x7fff9684180c]
+     1775 -[NSApplication run]  (in AppKit) + 555  [0x7fff965c2682]
+       1775 -[IDEApplication sendEvent:]  (in IDEKit) + 366  [0x103c95b71]
+         1775 -[NSApplication sendEvent:]  (in AppKit) + 4282  [0x7fff9662c170]
+           1775 -[NSApplication _handleKeyEquivalent:]  (in AppKit) + 526  [0x7fff9673488d]
+             1775 -[NSMenu performKeyEquivalent:]  (in AppKit) + 281  [0x7fff96735c3a]
+               1775 CFRunLoopRunSpecific  (in CoreFoundation) + 230  [0x7fff8e744ae6]
+                 1775 __CFRunLoopRun  (in CoreFoundation) + 1724  [0x7fff8e7454dc]
+                   1775 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 308  [0x7fff8c3ba72a]
+                     1775 _dispatch_call_block_and_release  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 18  [0x7fff8c3b88ba]
+                       1775 __-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _onMainThreadInvokeWorker:]_block_invoke_3  (in AppKit) + 492  [0x7fff96995333]
+                         1775 __-[NSDocument performAsynchronousFileAccessUsingBlock:]_block_invoke_6  (in AppKit) + 94  [0x7fff96964cad]
+                           1775 -[IDEEditorDocument continueFileAccessUsingBlock:]  (in IDEKit) + 71  [0x103db69db]
+                             1775 -[NSDocument continueFileAccessUsingBlock:]  (in AppKit) + 227  [0x7fff96964898]
+                               1775 __-[NSDocument saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_1  (in AppKit) + 845  [0x7fff96969702]
+                                 1775 -[NSDocument _fileCoordinator:coordinateReadingContentsAndWritingItemAtURL:byAccessor:]  (in AppKit) + 248  [0x7fff9697b25c]
+                                   1775 -[NSFileCoordinator(NSPrivate) _coordinateReadingItemAtURL:options:writingItemAtURL:options:error:byAccessor:]  (in Foundation) + 829  [0x7fff96471e65]
+                                     1775 -[NSFileCoordinator(NSPrivate) _invokeAccessor:orDont:thenRelinquishAccessClaimForID:]  (in Foundation) + 207  [0x7fff9646ea8d]
+                                       1775 __-[NSDocument saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_7  (in AppKit) + 1313  [0x7fff96985c80]
+                                         1775 __-[NSDocument saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_14  (in AppKit) + 502  [0x7fff9698535a]
+                                           1775 -[NSDocument _preserveContentsIfNecessaryAfterWriting:toURL:forSaveOperation:version:error:]  (in AppKit) + 286  [0x7fff9697b004]
+                                             1775 -[NSDocument _preserveContentsOfURL:forReason:comment:options:error:]  (in AppKit) + 335  [0x7fff96978c88]
+                                               1775 -[NSFileVersion(NSPrivate) _setDocumentInfo:]  (in Foundation) + 54  [0x7fff9648e905]
+                                                 1775 GSLibrarySetGenerationInfoValueForKey  (in GenerationalStorage) + 620  [0x7fff8eab60bf]
+                                                   1775 ipc_set_info_value  (in GenerationalStorage) + 250  [0x7fff8eaa714d]
+                                                     1775 mach_msg  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 73  [0x7fff95131d71]
+                                                       1775 mach_msg_trap  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff9513267a]
```

Answer (score 6):

Do you have any anti-virus software on your system?
I had same problem until I turned off the anti-virus protection.

Comment: I have Kaspersky AV on my system, and was experiencing exactly the problem described.  Stopping the AV application prevented the beachball.  Sadly adding my dev folder as an exclusion on the AV didn't fix the problem, so I have no AV while coding. :-(

Comment: i'm on a corporate network with a proxy.  ran wireshark during slowdown and saw some proxy authentication errors. my theory is Xcode is using the file save as a chance to update something.  i disabled documentation update and it is working better!

Comment: +1 I found that Sophos was adding about a 20 second delay on every file save.

Comment: Brilliant! If only it was possible to pause it and not remove "on-access scanning"