# xcode 4.3.2 becomes unresponsive on editing/saving a file

Tags: xcode4.3

this is just driving me nuts. Just downloaded the Xcode 4.3.2 app from mac app store. Now, sometimes upon editing and then saving a file, Xcode becomes unresponsive for 5-10 seconds. The rotating wheel icon displays continuously.

Is there some background task going on when I save a file, may be some build checks or something which can be turned off or something else, can somebody help me out here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the antivirus that I have installed is causing some problem. Turning off its realtime protection did the trick for me. I found a similar tip over in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8160064/206613)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's probably downloading documentation and/or doing some initial indexing.

If you look at the activity monitor (the box in the center of the iTunes-like toolbar), you might see what's going on, or a tiny number badge which, when clicked on, shows you what else is going on behind the scenes in Xcode.

If the problem persists for a long time (i.e. more than an hour or so), it may also have something to do with the [while-typing parsing that LLVM provides (look at this web page under the "Apple LLVM Compiler" section)](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/).  This is known as "Live Issues", which you can turn off in Xcode's General preferences.

Comment: I checked the activity monitor - it did not change, and turning off the 'Live Issues' didn't work either. The problems has been continuing for a while now.

Comment: Well shoot... in Terminal.app, try running "top" and see what processes are hogging your CPU (and you can quit "top" by hitting control-C). Xcode might have spawned off some other goodies by accident or ones that need to be turned off.

Comment: Using `top` or Activity Monitor app is not helping very much. Also I have seen that this weird thing happens only in .h and .m files, not in the xib files.